# How to collapse a view in Xamarin.iOS in runtime?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout

In Android we can use ViewStates.Gone on a view's Visibility, but in iOS if you set the Hidden property to false, the view will still take up space. 
I am using Auto Layout, so I thought of changing the dimension constraints like:

```
FilterLayout.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(0f).Active = true;
```

It works once.
But when I try to expand the view again by calling

```
FilterLayout.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(0f).Active = false;
```

or just setting a new value:

```
FilterLayout.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(200f).Active = true;
```

or writing both lines, 
the size does not change.

(FilterLayout's size is originally defined by its subviews, where the first subview's top matches its topMargin, and the last subview's bottom matches its bottomMargin.)

I even tried changing the neighboring container's constraint, so it doesn't attach to FilterLayout, and the result is, FilterLayout gets compressed, and changing the constraints back does not do anything.

On the top of the page is SearchLayout, below FilterLayout, below UserSearchList.

Hiding FilterLayout works:

```
FilterLayout.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UserSearchList.TopAnchor).Active = false;
UserSearchList.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(FilterLayout.BottomAnchor).Active = false;

SearchLayout.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UserSearchList.TopAnchor).Active = true;
UserSearchList.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(SearchLayout.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
```

Tried showing it again:

```
SearchLayout.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UserSearchList.TopAnchor).Active = false;
UserSearchList.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(SearchLayout.BottomAnchor).Active = false;

FilterLayout.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(UserSearchList.TopAnchor).Active = true;
UserSearchList.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(FilterLayout.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
```

It doesn't matter if you set only one view's contraint, or both, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Xamarin forum, and the fact is, by setting the ...Anchor property, you are adding a constraint, not modifying it, even if you write the same line with .Active = false.
That explains why the layout changed for the first time, but not afterwards.

You need to cycle through the constraints to remove one:

```
foreach (NSLayoutConstraint constraint in FilterLayout.Constraints)
{
    if (constraint.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height)
    {
        FilterLayout.RemoveConstraint(constraint);
    }
}
```

Calling layoutIfNeeded does not affect this behaviour, but using StackView could be an alternative solution.

Comment: You can mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you need to force the layout update by calling layoutIfNeeded after setting your constraints:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiview.layoutifneeded?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Another suggestion is to put your views in StackViews. Then when you set the hidden property on your view inside the StackView, the StackView should automatically resize to its content size.